# Cassandra throwing NoHostAvailableException

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I am having 3 node cluster with replication factor 2 and one of my Cassandra node was down and I started receiving following exception in my java service in

```
org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraConnectionFailureException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
at org.springframework.cassandra.support.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:145)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(CqlTemplate.java:946)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlTemplate.java:930)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlTemplate.java:912)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:278)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:559)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:549)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:485)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:510)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:505)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.selectOne(CassandraTemplate.java:638)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.selectOne(CassandraTemplate.java:509)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.execute(CassandraQueryExecution.java:104)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$ResultProcessingExecution.execute(CassandraQueryExecution.java:143)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.AbstractCassandraQuery.execute(AbstractCassandraQuery.java:113)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:499)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.getSearchAppearanceCount(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor168.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
```

Cassandra Version: 3.0.0

Java Driver version: 3.3.0

After removing node(which was down) from DNS, I tried restarting my java service and I started getting exceptions

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host cassandra-activitydb.resdex.com/172.10.212.52:9042: Error during authentication of user naukCassandra : org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_ONE
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
at com.ie.naukri.activity_tracker.main.ApplicationConfig.main(ApplicationConfig.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Comment: Did you make sure that Cassandra on all the nodes was listening on the correct port? netstat -anp | grep 9042

Answer (score 0):

So my guess is that your SYSTEM_AUTH keyspace has a RF=1 and the node that went down had your authentication record (user row). You could try a different user who's data resided on an available host to get connected, and drop/recreate the affected users, etc. In general, ensure that the SYSTEM_AUTH table is replicated to something higher than 1 (with 3 nodes, I would simply change it to 3, but you could do 2 and hopefully be safe for a single node failure).

Comment: SYSTEM_AUTH is also configured with RF=2

Comment: Is this DSE or Apache? If DSE, check the dse_security keyspace as well. I've seen that one be set to 1 as well, which can cause problems with authorization. If not, and your system_auth=2, what I would do is run repair on each live node on the system_auth keyspace and then re-try to log in. You should be able to get in.

Comment: Its Apache, I am not having any keyspace with name dse_security. At the time of issue I did run repair on each live node and was able to login after half an hour.
But I am not able to understand why this occurred? What is the root cause of it?

Comment: So my thought is one of several things may have occurred: Either you created the user and then changed the RF to a higher value and didn't run repair, or you had a node become unavailable for more than 3 hours that contained the user record and repair was never run to catch it up. Basically an inconsistency issue where repair hasn't run to "fix" things - the downsides of a distributed system